# Trouble parsing and displaying AXIOS returned data

Tags: react-native

I am working on a Reat Native app and I have called an API via Axios.   I get back the response as expected however anything I try to extract the values fails with various errors.

This is the format of the response:  (This is actually stored in response.data.homes.home) and is all the data i want from the request.

[{"id":"0002","url":"https://www.url1.com","name":"name1","f_name":"f name1","x_id":"23212"},{"id":"0001","url":"https://www.url2.com","name":"name2","f_name":"f name2","x_id":"43234"},{"id":"0001","url":"https://www.url3.com","name":"name3","f_name":"f name3","x_id":"32334"}]

The key would be x_id.

Tried: (undefined is not an object evaluating response.map)

```
 <View>
      {response.map((item, index) => (
        <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
```

Tried: (undefined is not an object....)

```
 <FlatList
      data={JSON.stringify(response.data.homes.home)}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return <Text>{item.name}</Text>;
      }}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.x_id}
    />
```

All I am trying to do is simply display the returned values to the screen.  What am i missing here?

Comment: `data` is just a plain array. If you want to use a `Flatlist` then inside `data` pass parse array not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) converts a JavaScript object to a JSON string. The [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) component expects a `plain array` for its data prop.

If `response.data.homes.home` is already an array as your questions suggests, then use this for the data prop directly.

```js
data={response.data.homes.home}
```

If `response.data.homes.home` is a JSON string, use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
data={JSON.parse(response.data.homes.home)}
```

It might be advised to use a `state` for the `data` prop.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState();

React.useEffect(() => {
    // load data
    setData(response.data.homes.home);
}, [])

...

<FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return <Text>{item.name}</Text>;
      }}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.x_id}
    />
```